# Can't get AVPlayerLayer to display video in NSView

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, nsview, osx-lion, avplayer

I am trying to make a simple HLS player to control playback and display on a secondary monitor.  I am using AVFoundation on in 10.7 to control the playback.  I can successfully create the AVPlayerItem and the AVPlayer, but I am having problems actually getting the video to display within an NSView.

I must confess I am a Cocoa novice, and am coming from iOS development, so I may be missing something simple.  However I have spent 4-5 hours trying to get this to work, and I have been unsuccessful.

When I play the video from the AVPlayer, playback begins and I can hear audio.  However, no video is showing up.

I have tried to make it as simple as possible.  I have a NSViewController, where I add a AVPlayerLayer to it's view's layer:

```
AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
```

As far as I know, that is all I have to do.  However, video never appears within the view.

Has anyone had success adding a AVPlayerLayer to a NSView?  The AVFoundation documentation shows how this can be done with a UIView, and I have tried that method as well with no luck in NSView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try sending setWantsLayer:YES to your view before adding the sublayer.

```
[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
AVPlayerLayer * playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
```

Comment: That was it.  The AVFoundation docs show how to set this up on iOS by subclassing a UIView.  However, NSView does not have layerClass, which is one reason it wasn't working on my end.

So I subclassed a different way, and made sure to add the setWantsLayer, and it seems to work great!

Comment: On iOS, doesn't look like there's a "wantslayer" attribute/method

Comment: Setting the frame did the trick for me. Xcode doesn't recognize `setWantsLayer`.